# Neo4j Java driver throws "connection reset by peer" exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

We are using Spring Data Neo4j. All the queries work, however sometimes it throws an exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: Connection to the database failed; Error code 'N/A'; nested exception is org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ServiceUnavailableException: Connection to the database failed
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
```

and after some time it restores the connection.

How can this be fixed to restore the connection immediately?

Comment: Just an idea because there is not much context: do you consume the results after the query execution? It could be that you have open results that got closed before you post-process them.
So calling `consume()`, `list()` or similar to hydrate the results as fast as possible _could_ be a solution.

Answer (score 2):

This exception comes from Neo4j Java Driver, which throws it when connection gets interrupted. In general, there may be several reasons for this to happen.

For instance, this might happen when driver acquires a connection from internal connection pool that has been idle for too long. Some cloud providers limit connection idle time for load balancers. Driver may fail as soon as it tries using such connection.

You can enable [connection liveness check](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/4.3/org/neo4j/driver/Config.ConfigBuilder.html#withConnectionLivenessCheckTimeout-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) to assist with this. It makes sure that a short network exchange happens for every connection that has been idle over the configured timeout. If exchange fails, another connection is picked or established before it is provided for further driver usage. While this involves an extra network exchange, it is likely to prevent driver failures that might lead to higher-level retry management with potentially exponential delay. The timeout can be set to zero if you wish to test every connection.

Sample configuration:

```
var config = Config.builder()
                   .withConnectionLivenessCheckTimeout( 60000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS )
                   .build();

var driver = GraphDatabase.driver( URL, AuthTokens, config );
```